# How to encrypt video using RSA

Tags: rsa, public-key

I can encrypt the message using the RSA algorithm. But I do not know how to encrypt video.

Comment: What's wrong with the usual practice of [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem)?

Comment: Video is just a sequence of bytes with a special structure to them. I don't see any problems with encrypting said sequence of bytes.

Comment: @fgrieu I guess the problem is that mr.hiep doesn't know it...  XD

Answer (score 2):

RSA is not meant for bulk encryption. It's slow and has a lot of overhead.

As fgrieu mentions, you should use hybrid cryptography where you create a random symmetric key, encrypt the data with it and then encrypt the symmetric key using your RSA public key. For decryption first retrieve the symmetric (data or session) key and then decrypt the video.

A recent/common scheme would be RSA-OAEP with AES-GCM. AES-CTR may also be interesting as it allows you to skip in the encrypted stream (when implemented correctly). In other words, the cipher provides *random access* to the plaintext. In general you would like a symmetric cipher with good *online* properties for *streaming* video; an online cipher directly returns the ciphertext / plaintext when encrypting / decrypting.

Note that RSA-OAEP does not provide authenticity of the encrypted symmetric key: an adversary can simply encrypt another video if so required. The RSA-OAEP implementation should further be secure against side channel attacks.

---

The word "message" usually just means the input plaintext in cryptographic papers. In other words, the message is just a bunch of bits / bytes. So if you know how to encrypt a message of the correct size then you would also know how to encrypt video.